# Is there any way to echo an ssh session to a local terminal session

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am starting a server via ssh from various locations, and i want the terminal printout to be able to be viewed locally on the server, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly a lot of ways to be able to view the output of a session that is being run from a different terminal session.

One simple way is to log the output using a command like `tee`. This will write the output of a command both to your terminal and to a file at the same time. To capture all output and errors from starting a server, run

```
server_cmd 2>&1 | tee /path/to/logfile
```

To read the saved output in another session, simply read the saved log file `/path/to/logfile`.

Another more flexible way is to use a terminal multiplexer program such as [screen](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screen) [image: Install screen], [tmux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tmux) [image: Install tmux], or [byobu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/byobu) [image: Install byobu]. A terminal multiplexer allows you to attach to and detach from running terminal sessions. This gives you the ability to do view the output of running programs from more than one attached session, and much more. See Ubuntu's help page on [Byobu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu).

Comment: Thanks, I wanted a terminal multiplexer, I'll try them out once I get home.

Comment: @coolwithpie, great, definitely try `byobu` if you haven't tried any of them before, it is a wrapper around `screen` or `tmux`, it is very easy to get started with. Let me know if I can add anything to my answer to expand on what you're looking for.

Comment: @coolwithpie If this answer solves your problem perfectly, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? Thanks.